# How many permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ are there such that $|\pi (i) - i|\le 1$?

Tags: permutations

How many permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ are there such that $|\pi (i) - i|\le 1$?

How would I go about solving this with a proof and teaching it to a non-math major student?

Comment: for a fixed $i$, or did you mean to sum over $i$ from 1 to $n$?

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(n)$ denote tha number of such permutations.
Let $\pi$ be such a permutation.
Either $\pi(n)=n$ and the restriction to $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ is one of $f(n-1)$ smaller permutations of this kind. Or $\pi(n)=n-1$, necessarily $\pi(n-1)=n$ and the restriction to $\{1,\ldots,n-2\}$ is one of $f(n-2)$ smaller such permutations.
We obtain the recursion
$$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2).$$
We check $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$ and therefore conclude that $f(n)$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.